# Let $(a_n)$ be a decreasing sequence . If $(na_n)$ converges to zero, does the series $(a_n)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

I know the converse is true.
I feel that this statement is false, I'm trying to find some counter example.
Series $(a_n)$ converging implies $(a_n)$ converges to $0$ , and I tried sequences like $1/n$ (since I know $n^{-p}$ converges iff $p<1$) but I don't get any example.

Can you give me a *specific* counter example or give exact proof the statement in question.
Thanks!

Comment: The sequence $a_n = \frac{1}{n \ln n}$ is a counterexample. See if you can see why.

Comment: @TheoBendit Why are you giving an answer in the comment section?

Comment: @Arthur Because I fear answering elementary questions now. I've found I cannot properly predict which questions get closed and deleted, or how rapidly. I've also seen people be chastised for answering questions with duplicates, and although I searched fruitlessly on Approach0, I strongly suspected there was a duplicate I couldn't find. You'll find me delivering answers, or at least answer-worthy hints, in the comments a lot these days. I'm just trying to ride out EoQS as best I can, without getting one of these "low-quality contribution" bans.

Comment: @Arthur,  I don't believe the comment would be a sufficient answer, in particular I do believe that the comment as an answer would go foul of the EoQS as anticipated above

Comment: @CalvinKhor To be fair, I could easily have expanded it into an answer by going into why it is a counterexample. Pedagogically, I actually do prefer the more brief comment, with blanks to be filled in anyway. My new home in the comments could be a lot worse!

Comment: @TheoBendit So you use the comment box, against its explicit instruction (the comment box tells you to avoid answering questions), in order to loophole your way around answering a question you think maybe shouldn't be answered. I don't think it's as good of an approach as you think it is.

Comment: @TheoBendit Of course. I just thought "why are you giving an answer" might be interpreted to imply that your comment (a) is an Answer, and (b) should be left as one as-is, when neither are clear at all to me (at least, one should check one's EoQS tea leaves)

Comment: @Arthur It's certainly not ideal, I grant you, but it does two things: 1. Allows me to help the asker, and 2. Keeps me out of trouble. The system has much larger, more pressing problems right now. Right now, achieving those two goals is good enough for me. [Sorry, Mr Atwood.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments#comment5417_1560).

Comment: @CalvinKhor I think hints too belong in an answer post. And in this case, what the asker is explicitly asking for is a proof one way or an explicit counterexample the other way. An explicit counterexample, without any other fluff, is by definition a full answer in this case.

Comment: @TheoBendit I guess my take is 1) Maybe we shouldn't help the asker (if we shouldn't post an answer, then we shouldn't be answering), and 2) It shouldn't keep you out of trouble. It goes against so many explicitly stated rules of this community. Either such behavior should stop, or we should change the written rules. I will stop fighting this when the comment box says hints are okay.

Comment: @Arthur I respect the position, even if I can't quite bring myself to agree. Indeed, we had [a recent discussion](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34519/what-would-be-the-right-answer-to-the-question-is-this-a-typo-in-my-textbook?cb=1) in which multiple people, including two moderators, advocated answering a certain type of question in the comments. Perhaps you should float this on meta? Speaking of abusing the comment section, surely that is the proper place to discuss this issue?

Comment: @TheoBendit Oh Thanks !! I see it, Can you give one more example just for fun...? Just wanna get some idea of why it "works" or something.. if it makes sense

Comment: @simpleman5 You could consider $\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln n}}$ or $\frac{1}{n\ln(\ln(n))}$, as well as trivial variations like $\frac{2}{n\ln n}$. I haven't tutored this stuff in a while, so I'm not the best font of counterexamples.

Comment: @Arthur The EoQS has made clear a distinction between an answer to a question posed (arguably Theo's comment) and an acceptable Answer on a Question of this site (of which I see none possible to the current Q).  My sense is that "Maybe we shouldn't help the asker" even in good-faith is prbbly seen as unfriendly to those outside SE  and whatever reasoning led you there isn't in service of the longterm interests of math.SE. I've left many comments of this type and would prefer to discuss this on Meta.(PS you surely know the comment box won't say hints are okay, as that would be math.SE specific)

Comment: @TheoBendit Oh never mind.. Thanks!

Comment: @simpleman5, here's a sketch for a different one. For each $k$, and each $N$, the sums of $\frac1{kn}$ from $n=N$ to infinity diverge. So you can set $a_1=1$, then switch to $a_n = \frac1{2n}$, until $\sum_{n=1}^{n_1} a_n \ge 2$. Then you start including terms of the form $a_n = \frac1{3n}$. The sequence formed in this way is decreasing, $na_n\to 0$ as $n_k a_{n_k} = \frac1k\to 0$, and since we chose to make sure the partial sums of the first $n_k$ terms are larger than $k$, we get divergence. (Arthur: someone has probably written the above neatly but I have to leave now, irl calls me...)